# Is it possible for UIStackView to get focus in tvOS?

Tags: swift, tvos

I have two UILabels in a UIStackView.  Is it possible for the UIStackView to get focus and gestures in tvOS?

Answer (score 0):

Items **in** a stack view can receive focus, but not the stack view itself. By default, labels cannot receive focus either. Buttons are the most commonly items that receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a stack view focusable by subclassing the stackview, overriding canBecomeFocused and using that subclass:

```
class FocusableStackView: UIStackView {
    override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```